# How do I click on a link that is associated to a another DIV with Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm having a problem locating an item  to click that is related to a specific "row" in a div using the .click() function in Cypress.io.  Below is my example div table:

```
<div class="table"> 
  <div class="col-sm-10">Item 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 action">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-10">Item 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 action">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is click on the A link for a specified row.  For example, I want to click on the A link for the "row" that contains the text of Item 2.  I need to do this dynamically because the order of the items, as well as the names of the items,  may change depending upon data.

I'm trying something like this:

```
cy.get('div:contains("Item 2")').click()
```

But the div is not the clickable one, it is the following A in the code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Best Practices | Cypress - Selecting elements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements), the best way to do it is using dedicated `data-cy` attribute for your cypress tests, and then, within the tests, using CSS attribute selectors.

> Best Practice: Use data-* attributes to provide context to your selectors and insulate them from CSS or JS changes.

In your case, I would do it this way:

```
<div class="table"> 
   <div class="col-sm-10">Item 1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 action">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10">Item 2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 action">
    <a href="#" data-cy="item-2-anchor"><i class="fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
   </div>
</div>

cy.get('[data-cy="item-2-anchor"]').click();
```

I strongly recommend doing it this way project-wide, as it guarantees working tests despite any changes made to other attributes (`id`, `class`, `href` ..) under development.

Comment: I agree.. if it is possible you should put some sort of id's on what you are testing. If you  have access to the code I highly suggest that. What happens is later the structure of the HTML changes and the app is still usable, but your test break. Way better to target the specific element with a id that makes sense. I do not like using the data-cy attribute I prefer the id attribute, because it is slightly easier to select on..

Comment: Thanks for this direction.  Moving forward I will definitely work from this. However at this point, I can't have them change the attribute values of the divs.

Comment: @Maccurt see what you're saying - I've extended the cypress commands with cy.getByDataName - which selects on the `data-name` attribute (just in case we move away from Cypress) then I use id in the actual app code - to separate the testing and the code completely.

Answer (score 5):

```
cy.contains('div', 'Item 2').next().find('a').click()
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it is what most resembles what he seeks. wscourge's answer is obviously the correct answer

Comment: Yeah, I started to type out what you wrote and you beat me to it. I have some test I maintain at my job and they use cypress and they are doing selects on a div with the nth child with a nth sibling, and I put a stop to that..

Comment: Thank Sergio, you are correct. :) . I've tried one of your options, but Cypress is not locating the a.  CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'a', but never found it. Queried from element: <div.col-sm-10>

Comment: I had not seen that he is not an ancestor. Use next() instead of closes():
cy.contains('div', 'Item 2').next().find('a').click();

Comment: This is a good answer, it fits the pattern with which the HTML is created so is likely to be robust.